# qt in windows7 environment

Tags: windows, qt

I am having a problem with running an example from qt which uses win32 libraries. When I compile I don't get any errors but when I run it is not able to open the application (.exe) file in Windows 7. But when I compile this example in WindowsXP it works fine. Can anyone let me know whether I need to change my .pro file in order to get it worked under Windows 7?
Here is my .pro file:

```
# -------------------------------------------------
# Project created by QtCreator 2010-04-16T11:45:43
# -------------------------------------------------
QT += network
QT += xml
QT += opengl
TARGET = Application
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    Tools.cpp \
    Objects.cpp
HEADERS += mainwindow.h \
        Tools.h\
        Objects.h
unix { 
    OBJECTS_DIR = .obj
    MOC_DIR = .moc
}

# UNIX installation
isEmpty(PREFIX):PREFIX = /usr/local
unix { 
    headers.path = $$PREFIX/include/ZIP
    headers.files = $$HEADERS
    target.path = $$PREFIX/lib
    INSTALLS += headers \
        target
}
!mac:x11:LIBS += -ldns_sd
win32:LIBS += -ldnssd
LIBPATH = C:/Temp/mDNSResponder-107.6/mDNSWindows/DLL/Debug
INCLUDEPATH += c:/Temp/mDNSResponder-107.6/mDNSShared
```

Comment: For questions like this, it would be helpful to know more specifically what happens when it fails.  You said, Windows 7 "is not able to open the application."  What actually happens?  Do you get an error message?  What does the message say?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to help you find out what Qt DLLs are needed and copy them to the same folder as the .exe.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably because Windows can't find the Qt libraries.
Try placing the required Qt libraries (for instance QtNetwork4.dll, etc...) in the same directory as your .exe and see if it works.